# Is there a function that prevents a integer to be bigger or smaller than values (range)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to do something like this:

```
=MYFUNC(my_number, limit_down, limit_up)
```

If the number goes out of limits, bring it to the closest limit and some examples, what I want:

```
=MYFUNC(1, 4, 8) ==>  4
=MYFUNC(5, 4, 8) ==>  5
=MYFUNC(6, 4, 8) ==>  6
=MYFUNC(8, 4, 8) ==>  8
=MYFUNC(9, 4, 8) ==>  8
=MYFUNC(0, 4, 8) ==>  4
```

I can use `MAX` and `MIN` for this task, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: you may use the ternary conditional operator if you want to avoid `min` and `max`  `function MYFUNC(v, min, max){return v <= min ? min : v >= max ? max : v; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you state that you've already used MIN & MAX, but have you tried nesting them? You can't get a more compact expression than:

```
=min(max(number,lower_limit),upper_limit)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do the conditional checking without using apps script, you can use LAMBDA function like this, or just setup a named function.

```
=LAMBDA(INT,MIN,MAX,
 IF(INT <= MIN, MIN, IF(INT>= MAX, MAX, INT))
)(my_number, limit_down, limit_up)
```